# Name of the interface?

Tags: mobile-application, responsive-design

What is this kind of interface called? Moreover , it'd be a great help if someone tells me the application/environment which would help me implement such kind of interface best.Carefully note the plus turns into a cross when it is expanded,giving an option to minimize.I want that clearly.
P.S. I am a beginner and looking to develop an Android App only.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the interface style is called METRO.  The METRO style was made popular by Microsoft in Windows 8, that's where the flat, square styling comes from.  As far as the the cross turning into an X, this can be achieved by either JS or CSS.  Honestly the CSS route is easier.  You can create a  holding two other s that are a specific size and color.  Then to rotate it use CSS rotate and JS to apply an "active" class or do this on hover through CSS.

As far as a framework is concerned, personally I like Bootstrap or Foundation.  Both are responsive, grid based front-end frameworks that will allow you to easily achieve the above, desired style and design. They are also very well documented on their respective websites and are widely used so there is a ton of forum assistance like on StackExchange.

Your app/site can also be easily adapted for larger devices because it uses a responsive framework.

Below is a list of resources that can help you with different parts of my answer above:

- http://getbootstrap.com/
- http://foundation.zurb.com/
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript

Comment: @Alan, while this has resemblances with Metro and it even has the Metro word (which means "Subway" and it's what the app is meant for, measure ETA on public services), this is not a Metro interface, just a regular grid. The key to know that is in the behaviors (but also colors, space between elements and typography)

Comment: @Devin  this style is widely recognized at the "Microsoft Metro theme" from Windows 8+.  I do recognize that the app in the picture says Metro and that it is public transit themed, however the themeing style, colors and organization of the image is of the METRO style, stemming most recently from MS

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a tile layout or grid layout, pretty generic.

How it is can be implemented depends on technology you are going to use. If it is a web application that is accessed via browsers - HTML/CSS/Javascript(jQuery). Or you can use PhoneGap to make your HTML app look like a mobile app.

If you are going to create a native Android app - you will have to use their SDK.